# Remove a line in that meets a criteria and create a report of what was deleted

Tags: perl, delete-row

I'm new to perl and learning as I go. I get a pipe delimited csv file where each line has a state field in it. I need perl to delete any row that has a state code of MA and create a report showing the entire row it deleted.

Here is an example line from the file that has the state MA. The state code is the 9th field. These files contain any where from 200 to 90,000 records so each report should contain the entire list of lines that contained MA.

Thank you.

```
48975564|37274022|64645215|49740554|New|6649|2790|20140812165625|MA|20140812195525|Y||18|20140812201212|20140805153425|1|28|81602017|Default|DIALER-2|claglama|whyte|RMKT|Arts/Sciences|Associate of Arts|AAGS|ASSOCIATE OF ARTS IN GENERAL STUDIES|9049540951|20782|WEST HYATTSVILLE|||||3013648759|US|United States|UOP|N|N|N|N||Y
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Is there a particular part of this that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't tried anything.  I haven't learned how to delete from a csv and create a report.  I am pretty green.  This for a predictive dialer application.  I apologize if this out of the norm here.

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner might work for you:

```
perl -i -F'\|' -lane 'BEGIN {$bad = \*STDOUT} $F[8] eq "MA" ? $bad->print($_) : print' file.csv > bad.csv
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-F`: `split()` pattern for `-a` switch (//'s are optional)
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: I am hoping to put this on a cron and run automatically when a new list posts.  I am not sure how to put a one liner on a file.  I tried using the one-liner and including the actual directories. But got an error bad name after F'     #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


perl -i -F'\|' -lane 'BEGIN {$bad = \*STDOUT} $F[8] eq "MA" ? $bad->print($_) : print' /opt/avaya/pds/public/public/rcvfile1.raw > /opt/avaya/pds/reports/rcvfile1bad.csv

Comment: The answer is, I wouldn't try to put a one-liner in a cron job.  I suspect you have some studying to do.  Your goal is not hard, but only you know your exact environment and what your specs are.  Come back when you have a specific problem that we can help with, this is too Broad at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your Perl code so that it expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, in which case Perl does the `open` for you and you can read from the file using just `<>`.

You need to remove the newline from the end of each record using `chomp`, and `split` it on pipe characters `|`. The ninth field has index 8, and you can decide—based on its value—what to do with the current record.

It sounds like you want to print all lines that have `MA` in the ninth column to a report file, so you have to `open` that file first.

It makes sense to send everything that isn't printed to the report to STDOUT, so you would write something like this

So you could write this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $rep_fh, '>', 'report.txt';

while (my $line = <>) {
  chomp $line;
  my $f9 = (split /\|/, $line)[8];
  if ($f9 eq 'MA') {
    print $rep_fh $line, "\n";
  }
  else {
    print $line, "\n";
  }
}
```

As I described, this program takes the path to the input file as a parameter and sends the filtered output to STDOUT. The skipped lines are written to a file called `report.txt`.

If you put the Perl code into a file called `filter.pl` then you would run it like this

```
perl filter.pl myfile.txt > filtered.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

You could read in your file, line by line, and print the lines that match the specific regex `|MA|` to an error file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';
open my $errors, '>', 'error.txt';
open my $new, '>', 'new.txt';

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    if (/\|MA\|/){
        print $errors "$_\n" ;
        next; # Skip any lines that contain |MA|
    }
    print $new "$_\n"; # Print all the remaining lines to a new file
}
```